# Cannot read a gzip compressed file

Tags: c, http, compression, gzip

I'm trying to make a small web server in C. I have a function that reads from a file that a client has requested.

```c
char* readFile(char* path)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");
    if(file == NULL) return NULL;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* data = (char*)calloc(fsize, sizeof(char));
    fread(data, fsize, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    return data;
}
```

and it works fine. But I want to make things faster for clients so I compressed HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files but this time the function doesn't seem to work although the client accepts gzip content encoding and I have changed opening mode to :

```c
 FILE* file = fopen(path, "rb");
```

All I see when I request the home page (the only one I have) using firefox is this :

```
ï¿½Obia
```

In Chrome the page doesn't even load and I get this error:

```
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I also added the `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header

Comment: Did you change the HTTP response header to indicate that the content being served is gzip compressed? I believe that you must set `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the response.

Comment: *although the client accepts gzip content encoding* - and where are you telling the client the content is gzipped ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I also added `Content-Encoding:gzip;` response header

Comment: *I have a function that reads from a file ... and it works fine.* Does it?  How would you know if it failed?  You're not checking any return values.  At all.